# Restrict users post for himself

Tags: posts, users, user-access, limit

I am trying to build a system that lists users posts only (that I have managed to code) but also restricts users from seeing eachothers posts.

If user A has his post under: domain.com/category/postA and he will pass this URL to user B, User B will either be redirected to main page or will be shown 404.

So for achives I do:

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?> 

<?php get_header(); ?>

// code of the loop

<?php get_footer(); ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php header( 'Location: http://www.domain.com' ) ; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And this works fine, but I am struggling with protecting users post.

I tried putting this code to functions. But it looks like is_single doesn't work here. Without is_single protection works (404 is shown to userB), but it also hides widget for user A.

```
function __set_all_posts_for_author( $query ) {
  if (is_single()) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $query->set( 'author', $current_user->ID );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', '__set_all_posts_for_author' );
```

Is there any better way (more secure) to achieve this goal ?

Comment: what you mean by `(more secure)` ?

Comment: Firstly I would like it to work, and then I would like to check with You guys if you can see potential weakness of such a method. I guess what I mean is to check my logic ...

Comment: as I think you are getting ID from core functions, there is no any weakness, unless you get any input from user.

Comment: Thx for checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: (edited code a little)

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
function my_page_template_redirect() {
    global $post;
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if( is_single() ){
            if( $post->post_author != get_current_user_id() ){
                wp_redirect( 'IN ANY PAGE' );
            }
        }
    }else{
        wp_redirect( 'IN ANY PAGE' );
    }
}
```